# C optimization - low level code

Tags: c++, c, optimization, memory-management

I'm trying to write a memory allocator comparable to dlmalloc which is the malloc used in glibc. dlmalloc is a best-fit allocator with block splitting and it retains a pool of recently used blocks before consolidating the blocks into large ones again. The allocator I'm writing does it first fit style instead.

My problem is two fold : (1) that the test times for my code are highly irregular compared to those of glibc malloc and (2) some days the average run time on my code will be 3 to 4 times greater; (2) is not a big deal but I would like to understand why glibc malloc does not suffer in the same way. Further in this post shows a sample of the behavior described in (1) between malloc and my code. Sometimes the times a batch of a 1000 tests will have an average time much higher than that of malloc( problem (2) above), sometimes the averages are the same. But, the test times for a batch of tests on my code are always highly irregular (problem (1) above); meaning that there are jumps in time in a batch of tests to 20 times the average and these jumps are interspersed in otherwise regular (close to average) times. glibc malloc does not do this.

The code I'm working on follows.

===================================

```
/* represent an allocated/unallocated  block of memory */
struct Block {

    /* previous allocated or unallocated block needed for consolidation but not used in allocation */
    Block* prev;
    /* 1 if allocated and 0 if not */
    unsigned int tagh;
   /* previous unallocated block */
   Block* prev_free;
   /* next unallocated block  */
   Block* next_free;
   /* size of current block */
   unsigned int size;
};

#define CACHE_SZ 120000000

/* array to be managed by allocator */
char arr[CACHE_SZ] __attribute__((aligned(4)));

/* initialize the contiguous memory located at arr for allocator */
void init_cache(){
/* setup list head node that does not change */
   Block* a = (Block*)  arr;
  a->prev = 0; 
  a->tagh = 1;
  a->prev_free = 0;
  a->size = 0;

/* setup the usable data block */
  Block* b = (Block*) (arr + sizeof(Block));
  b->prev = a; 
  b->tagh = 0;
  b->prev_free = a;
  b->size = CACHE_SZ - 3*sizeof(Block);
  a->next_free = b;

/* setup list tail node that does not change */
  Block* e = (Block*)((char*)arr + CACHE_SZ - sizeof(Block)); 
  e->prev = b;
  e->tagh = 1;
  e->prev_free = b;
  e->next_free = 0;
  e->size = 0;
  b->next_free = e;
}

char* alloc(unsigned int size){
  register Block* current = ((Block*) arr)->next_free; 
  register Block* new_block;

/* search for a first-fit block */

   while(current != 0){
       if( current->size >= size + sizeof(Block)) goto good;
       current = current->next_free;
   }

/* what to do if no decent size block found */
   if( current == 0) {
       return 0;
   }

/* good block found */
good:
/* if block size is exact return it */
   if( current->size == size){
       if(current->next_free != 0) current->next_free->prev_free = current->prev_free;
       if(current->prev_free != 0) current->prev_free->next_free = current->next_free;
       return (char* ) current + sizeof(Block);
   }

/* otherwise split the block */

   current->size -= size + sizeof(Block); 

    new_block = (Block*)( (char*)current + sizeof(Block) + current->size);
    new_block->size = size;
    new_block->prev = current;
    new_block->tagh = 1;
   ((Block*)((char*) new_block + sizeof(Block) + new_block->size ))->prev = new_block;

   return (char* ) new_block + sizeof(Block);
}

main(int argc, char** argv){
    init_cache();
    int count = 0;

/* the count considers the size of the cache arr */
    while(count < 4883){

/* the following line tests malloc; the quantity(1024*24) ensures word alignment */
   //char * volatile p = (char *) malloc(1024*24);
/* the following line tests above code in exactly the same way */
    char * volatile p = alloc(1024*24);
        count++;

    }
}
```

=====================================

I compile the above code simply with :

g++ -O9 alloc.c

and run a simple test that always goes to split the block and never returns an exact size block :

bash$ for((i=0; i<1000; i++)); do (time ./a.out) 2>&1|grep real; done

sample outputs of the test for my code and glibc malloc are as follows :

my code :

```
real    0m0.023s
real    0m0.109s    <----- irregular jump >
real    0m0.024s
real    0m0.086s
real    0m0.022s
real    0m0.104s    <----- again irregular jump >
real    0m0.023s
real    0m0.023s
real    0m0.098s
real    0m0.023s
real    0m0.097s
real    0m0.024s
real    0m0.091s
real    0m0.023s
real    0m0.025s
real    0m0.088s
real    0m0.023s
real    0m0.086s
real    0m0.024s
real    0m0.024s
```

malloc code (nice and regular stays close to 20ms) :

```
real    0m0.025s
real    0m0.024s
real    0m0.024s
real    0m0.026s
real    0m0.024s
real    0m0.026s
real    0m0.025s
real    0m0.026s
real    0m0.026s
real    0m0.025s
real    0m0.025s
real    0m0.024s
real    0m0.024s
real    0m0.024s
real    0m0.025s
real    0m0.026s
real    0m0.025s
```

Note the malloc code times are more regular. At other, unpredictable times, my code has 0m0.070s instead of 0m0.020s so that the average run time is close to 70ms instead of 25ms (problem (2) above) but this is not shown here. In this case I was lucky enough to have it running close to the average of malloc (25ms)

The questions are, (1) how can I modify my code to have more regular times such as glibc malloc ? and (2) how can I make it even faster than glibc malloc if this is possible because I have read that dlmalloc is a characteristically balanced allocator and is not the fastest (only considering split/best-fit/first-fit allocators not others) ?

Comment: 20 ms is a very short time for benchmarking - just two time slices - if another task takes some CPU time you'll get a much longer wall clock time. Either increase the length of your test or perhaps use `user` time rather than `real` time for comparison.

Comment: Very interesting question! I would like to point out, that there are many more irregular jumps in your code's output. As I see it, everything that is greater than 0m0.030s is irregular when comparing your output to malloc output

Comment: Another possible problem: you appear to have a large static allocation for your memory pool - this is probably not completely wired in at program start up so you may well get page faults when you access a new page for the first time.

Comment: @Paul R in fact there page faults are not the problem after profiling with perf but that was my first guess too. There is more correspondence with the irregularities and cache misses but I can't see why there would be more cache misses. EDIT : I'll double check this with perf again now but the heap is similarly accessed is it not, and therefore subject to the same page faults?

Comment: See if you can find the HOARD allocator library and benchmarks on the web anywhere.  The guys that wrote and researched the benchmark code answered your question, but I couldn't find it again with a quick search.  This was part of a major project for me in the ~2000s time frame...  However, SmartHeap ended up winning (even with it's crazy source cost)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use 'real' time: Try 'user' + 'sys'. Average over a large number of iterations. The Problem is twofold: (a) your process is not alone on the processor, it's interrupted depending on what other processes do, (b) time measurement with time has a granularity. I'm not sure what it is today, but in former times it was just the size of a time slice => 1/100 s.

Comment: I do not think that would cause an issue as we are comparing two outputs measured with the same method but measuring a different function.

Comment: The method is not deterministic. That _is_ a problem.

Comment: @M.E.L: Yes, but you'd expect BOTH allocation functions to have a similar range of error if that is the case. I too have run the above code, and it's clearly a significant difference between the two solutions. I have a vague theory, but I have not yet proven it properly.

Comment: @M.E.L. Hmm.. I still do not understand as everything else in both case is the same except the method benchmarked and the output. But I will trust in your expertise as you probably have more experience in c programing than I do.

Comment: "Yes, but you'd expect BOTH allocation functions to have a similar range of error" => That's true. One idea is, that malloc never traps to the system in your use case, but your code does. Implicitely. Because your static array is probably mapped to the same read only page (by the operating system) and will be mapped to a "real" memory page when you write on it. Test: Does anything change when your write some arbitrary value on the array before the test? (You would have to move the time measurement into the program).

Comment: @Mats Petersson, I agree. Why does malloc not suffer the same delays in real time?

Comment: @19greg96: I'm only guessing too, but my experience is, that benchmarking with 'time' has some pitfalls. Other processes interrupting and interacting via caches, paging, whatever is one of them. But you can get reliable and reproducible benchmarks by folowing the advice in my answer and if possible run the benchmark in single user mode (no GUI, no other users, no sshd ...).

Comment: One thing is clear: There is some randomness afoot. And it's not in the program - so this allocator and malloc interact with the environment in a different way. Page faults and their effect on scheduling is one possibility. But it's just useless to argue "how can that be" and not trying to better the measurement method which IS wide open to external influence.

Comment: @M.E.L. your test proves your page faulting theory correct. Thanks a lot.

Comment: the next question would be is why does using static memory space cause all that page faulting while using heap memory with malloc does not?

Answer (score 5):

Right, I have compared both solutions, and run them in a few different variants. I don't KNOW for sure what the problem is, but my speculation is that a large part of the time is spent on "creating a large contiguous slab of 1200000000 bytes". If I reduce the size, and still perform the same number of allocatoions, the time goes down.

Another piece of evidence pointing at this is that the `system` time is a large portion of `real` time, where `user` time is nearly nothing.

Now, on MY system, it doesn't really wobble that much up and down once I've run these things a few times with high memory load. That's quite likely because once I've swapped out a bunch of old gunk that has accumulated in the memory, the system simply has plenty of "spare" pages to use for my process. When the memory is more constrained (because I've let the system go do some other things, such as do some database work on the "website" that I experiment on [it's a "sandbox" version of a real website, so it has real data in the database, and can quickly fill memory and such], I get more variation until I clear out memory quite a bit again.

But I think the key to the "mystery" is that the system time is the vast portion of the time used. It's also notable that when using `malloc` with large blocks, the memory is actually not being "really allocated". And when allocating smaller blocks, it seems that `malloc` is actually more clever in some way, and is faster than the "optimised" alloc - at least for larger amounts of memory. Don't ask me exactly how that works.

Here's some evidence:

I changed the `main` in the code to do:

```
#define BLOCK_SIZE (CACHE_SZ / 5000)

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    init_cache();
    int count = 0;
    int failed = 0;
    size_t size = 0;

/* the count considers the size of the cache arr */
    while(count < int((CACHE_SZ / BLOCK_SIZE) * 0.96) ){

/* the following line tests malloc; the quantity(1024*24) ensures word alignment */
   //char * volatile p = (char *) malloc(1024*24);
/* the following line tests above code in exactly the same way */
    char * volatile p;
    if (argc > 1) 
        p = (char *)malloc(BLOCK_SIZE);
    else
        p = alloc(BLOCK_SIZE);
    if (p == 0)
    {
        failed++;
        puts("p = NULL\n");
    }
    count++;
    size += BLOCK_SIZE;
    }
    printf("Count = %d, total=%zd, failed=%d\n", count, size, failed);
}
```

And then varied CACHE_SZ and ran with or without an argument to use `alloc` or `malloc` option:

So, with cache-size 12000000  (12MB):

The figures are:

```
real    0m0.008s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.007s
Count = 4800, total=11520000, failed=0

real    0m0.007s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.006s
Count = 4800, total=11520000, failed=0

real    0m0.008s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.006s
Count = 4800, total=11520000, failed=0

real    0m0.014s
user    0m0.003s
sys 0m0.010s
```

And a few runs with `malloc`:

```
real    0m0.010s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.009s
Count = 4800, total=11520000, failed=0

real    0m0.017s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.015s
Count = 4800, total=11520000, failed=0

real    0m0.012s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.010s
Count = 4800, total=11520000, failed=0

real    0m0.021s
user    0m0.007s
sys 0m0.013s
Count = 4800, total=11520000, failed=0

real    0m0.010s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.008s
Count = 4800, total=11520000, failed=0

real    0m0.009s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.007s
```

Making the cache-size 10x larger gives the following results for `alloc`:

```
real    0m0.038s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.036s
Count = 4800, total=115200000, failed=0

real    0m0.040s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.037s
Count = 4800, total=115200000, failed=0

real    0m0.045s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.043s
Count = 4800, total=115200000, failed=0

real    0m0.044s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.043s
Count = 4800, total=115200000, failed=0

real    0m0.046s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.043s
Count = 4800, total=115200000, failed=0

real    0m0.042s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.042s
```

And with `malloc`:

```
real    0m0.026s
user    0m0.004s
sys 0m0.021s
Count = 4800, total=115200000, failed=0

real    0m0.027s
user    0m0.002s
sys 0m0.023s
Count = 4800, total=115200000, failed=0

real    0m0.022s
user    0m0.002s
sys 0m0.018s
Count = 4800, total=115200000, failed=0

real    0m0.016s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.015s
Count = 4800, total=115200000, failed=0

real    0m0.027s
user    0m0.002s
sys 0m0.024s
Count = 4800, total=115200000, failed=0
```

And another 10x with `alloc`:

```
real    0m1.408s
user    0m0.002s
sys 0m1.395s
Count = 4800, total=1152000000, failed=0

real    0m1.517s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m1.505s
Count = 4800, total=1152000000, failed=0

real    0m1.478s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m1.466s
Count = 4800, total=1152000000, failed=0

real    0m1.401s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m1.389s
Count = 4800, total=1152000000, failed=0

real    0m1.445s
user    0m0.002s
sys 0m1.433s
Count = 4800, total=1152000000, failed=0

real    0m1.468s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m1.458s
Count = 4800, total=1152000000, failed=0
```

With `malloc`:

```
real    0m0.020s
user    0m0.002s
sys 0m0.017s
Count = 4800, total=1152000000, failed=0

real    0m0.022s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.020s
Count = 4800, total=1152000000, failed=0

real    0m0.027s
user    0m0.005s
sys 0m0.021s
Count = 4800, total=1152000000, failed=0

real    0m0.029s
user    0m0.002s
sys 0m0.026s
Count = 4800, total=1152000000, failed=0

real    0m0.020s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.019s
Count = 4800, total=1152000000, failed=0
```

If we change the code to make `BLOCK_SIZE` a constant of 1000, the difference between the `alloc` and `malloc` gets much smaller. Here's the `alloc` results:

```
 Count = 1080000, total=1080000000, failed=0

real    0m1.183s
user    0m0.028s
sys 0m1.137s
Count = 1080000, total=1080000000, failed=0

real    0m1.179s
user    0m0.017s
sys 0m1.143s
Count = 1080000, total=1080000000, failed=0

real    0m1.196s
user    0m0.026s
sys 0m1.152s
Count = 1080000, total=1080000000, failed=0

real    0m1.197s
user    0m0.023s
sys 0m1.157s
Count = 1080000, total=1080000000, failed=0

real    0m1.188s
user    0m0.021s
sys 0m1.147s
```

And now `malloc`:

```
Count = 1080000, total=1080000000, failed=0

real    0m0.582s
user    0m0.063s
sys 0m0.482s
Count = 1080000, total=1080000000, failed=0

real    0m0.586s
user    0m0.062s
sys 0m0.489s
Count = 1080000, total=1080000000, failed=0

real    0m0.582s
user    0m0.059s
sys 0m0.483s
Count = 1080000, total=1080000000, failed=0

real    0m0.590s
user    0m0.064s
sys 0m0.477s
Count = 1080000, total=1080000000, failed=0

real    0m0.586s
user    0m0.075s
sys 0m0.473s
```

Comment: i think the time goes down because there is less memory to allocate so the test terminates earlier than before. i fell for the trap.

Comment: @user2616927: Yes, but if you look at my 12GB size, you'll see that this is not the reason.

Comment: thanks you make a good point. I wonder how malloc gets that right. please check back later... i must be off now

Comment: Your analysis is a good one thanks a lot. I followed your lead and charted the performance of alloc and malloc using an increasing block size while keeping the number of allocations constant. It shows that alloc is faster at smaller blocks but malloc overtakes at larger blocks. The overtaking could be because malloc uses mmap to directly map memory for larger blocks. Thus your post is very useful thank you because it points out to me the completely incorrect way I was approaching the "benchmarking" measurements.

Comment: But, (I don't like buts, but...) it still doesn't explain why alloc has such erratic sys times and malloc's are so smooth. My theory is that when malloc has smooth sys times it is because it's calling mmap to map the memory directly thus moving directly in to kernel mode spending most of its time there and thus maybe it doesn't suffer the same number of interrupts that alloc experiences in user space. If this is right, then I would mark your as the correct answer.

Comment: I've proved my theory incorrect by disabling malloc mmap behaviour with the malopt() call. Disabling mmap behaviour makes no difference to malloc timings.

Comment: Sorry, not quite sure how `malloc` does it. It may be that it gives hints to the kernel, or it is more clever with alignment, or something else.

Comment: The problem is that the mass time difference is spent in system time in kernel mode. I've check with perf that there are no alignment faults in both malloc and alloc. I've also checked page faults and they are the same for both. I even locked the pages into RAM to eliminate any possible page faults. I think it has something to do with locality but no clue how.

Comment: I think I've come a step closer to solving the problem. I set linux timing functions around the test loop excluding the init_cache() function. In the init_cache function I zero out every byte of memory so to ensure that it is physically present in memory as suggested by M.E.L. I run linux mlockall() to lock all pages in in the process. Now malloc's performance is identical to what it was before and alloc is much much faster at this size block (1024*24) which agrees with my previous measurements but not yours; ie that alloc is faster for small blocks but slower for large.

Comment: The "real" times (wallclock time) measured by unix time when adding the memory zeroing code to init_cache() affect both the malloc and alloc test in exactly the same way; erratic and much longer times. I am happy go with the idea that the problem is due to page faulting of the static memory area. If so I would have to mark M.E.L. correct since he was the first to mention the page fault hypothesis.